# Any method of R to increasing the execution speed for stopwords in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm actually looking for a speeding up my execution speed for my R script. I've a data set which I call refdata with 127155 rows and mapdata with 2013 rows and I also merge the data and calls it "merged"

The problem is when I use the block of code for removing stopwords, it consumes a lot of time and in my case, it goes upto 10 mins. Any solutions on how can I optimized it?

NOTE:- Also tried apply function and still the removing stopword block takes up a lot of time.

```
refdata<-data.table::fread("refdata_127155.tsv", header=FALSE, sep="\t",quote="")
names(refdata) <- c("Id","Title","URL","Description","docText")
mapdata<-data.table::fread("mapdata_2013.tsv", header=FALSE, sep="\t", quote = "")
names(mapdata) <- c("Id","Name","docText")

 str(refdata)
 str(mapdata)
merged <- rbind(refdata, mapdata,fill=TRUE)

  ## cleaning the data sets

  prep_fun = function(x) {
    x %>%
      # make text lower case
      str_to_lower %>%
      #str_to_lower(x)
      # remove non-alphanumeric symbols
      str_replace_all("[^[:alnum:]]", " ") %>%
      # collapse multiple spaces
      str_replace_all("\\s+", " ")

    # if(type=='keedocumentclassification'){
    #    stopwords_regex = paste(stopwords('en'), collapse = '\\b|\\b')#typeof(stopwords_regex)
    #    stopwords_regex = paste0('\\b', stopwords_regex, '\\b') 
    #    str_replace_all(x,stopwords_regex, '')
    #  }
  }


  refdata$docText_clean = prep_fun(refdata$docText)
  mapdata$docText_clean = prep_fun(mapdata$docText)
  merged$docText_clean = prep_fun(merged$docText)

# Till here the above code block works fine with good processing speed.
  stopwords_regex = paste(stopwords('en'), collapse = '\\b|\\b')#typeof(stopwords_regex)
  stopwords_regex = paste0('\\b', stopwords_regex, '\\b')
  removestopword_prep_fun = function(x) {
    x %>%
      str_replace_all(stopwords_regex, '')
  }

# The problem comes here. When I run the below block. it takes more than 10 mins to execute which is pretty huge time to process
refdata$docText_clean = removestopword_prep_fun(refdata$docText_clean)
mapdata$docText_clean = removestopword_prep_fun(mapdata$docText_clean)
merged$docText_clean = removestopword_prep_fun(merged$docText_clean)
#refdata$docText_clean<-lapply(refdata$docText_clean,removestopword_prep_fun)
#mapdata$docText_clean<-lapply(mapdata$docText_clean,removestopword_prep_fun)
#merged$docText_clean<-lapply(merged$docText_clean,removestopword_prep_fun)
```

I don't know why it takes so much time to execute and the API later returns 502 Proxy error that's due to the time consuming factor of this block of code.
Any idea of how can I improvise the above block of code and make it a bit faster.

Comment: What are the next steps of the analysis? If you are producing some kind of document term matrix, it would be much faster to remove stopwords from that matrix instead of the actual text. That's how it's normally done.

Comment: Yes, trying to create the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not post example data. Otherwise I could have shown you how to remove stopwords after creating the matrix. You could use `quanteda` for example. https://quanteda.io/reference/dfm.html